# Simply request an url in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, arduino, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I have running a very basic web server on my arduino which turns the led on when typing in the url (.../?ledOn) and turning it off when typing in (.../?ledOff).

Now i have found a video on how to control these two states with a very simple looking objective c code from this website [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15932/electronics-for-iphone-developers-tutorial-control-a-led-from-your-iphone):

```
- (IBAction)switchPressed:(id)sender { 
    UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *) sender; 
    if (theSwitch.isOn) { 
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@".../?ledOn"]; 
        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
        [myWebView loadRequest:req]
    }
}
```

So i tried to convert this code into swift, but there is an error, while creating the `NSURL` variable, I get a variable of type `NSURL?`

---

The current Swift attempt looks like:

```
var url = NSURL(string: ".../?buttonOn") 
var reqest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(url))
```

Comment: Can you post your converted code to Swift? Maybe it could be a problem with the optionals but it's impossible to say without taking a look at the code...

Comment: `var url = NSURL(string: ".../?buttonOn")
var reqest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(url))`

Comment: This code snippet is loading a web view in order to call the request. Do you really need that web view (i.e. to let the user visually inspect HTML being fed back)? If not, there are better ways to do that.

Comment: No the whole process should run in the background! Could you tell me a better (simpler) way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest replacing web view with `NSURLSession` call. This, by the way, eliminates the need to build the `NSURLRequest`, too.

Thus:

```
@IBAction func switchPressed(sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.on {
        let url = NSURL(string: ".../?ledOn")!
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in
            // parse `data` or examine `error` here, e.g.
            //
            // if error != nil {
            //     println("\(error)")
            // }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Or, if you need to update the UI reporting the error, make sure to dispatch that back to the main queue:

```
@IBAction func switchPressed(sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.on {
        let url = NSURL(string: ".../?ledOn")!
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    //update UI reporting error here
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Three ways to fix it:

First one: Declare url constant as optional

```
let url : NSURL? = NSURL(string: "http://korfay.ddns.net/?buttonOn")
if let unwrappedURL = url {
    var reqest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    // do the work here
}
```

Second one: Force the url constant to show the value (it could crash if the value is nil):

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://korfay.ddns.net/?buttonOn")
var reqest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
```

Third one: Forced unwrapping:

```
let url : NSURL! = NSURL(string: "http://korfay.ddns.net/?buttonOn")
var reqest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked but i needed this web view... But doesn't matter, Thanks.